# How to create a regex pattern equal to 1,2,3

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently, on the project, they have a pattern `[^0-9,]` and it replaces (String.prototype.replace) everything that we don't need. Except it's not so great. We can add a comma to the start and to the end of the string.

What do I need and I can't do it no matter how hard I try)

1. first should be a number in the range 0-9
2. after the first number should be a comma (one comma) or a number or numbers (0-9)
3. at the end of the line shouldn't be a comma

Correct example,

```
1,2,3
```

Incorrect,

```
,,,,1,,2dgd,d,
1,2,3,
,1,2,,,3
```

UPD: The method String.prototype.replace() is used on the project.

I'll be grateful if you help me!

Comment: What does the correct example and incorrect example means?

Comment: Correct example means that I can add numbers and commas to the input, Incorrect means that I can't add it.

For instance, currently the use js replace method and the pattern is [^0-9,]. I can add to the input numbers and commas, but not everything else. It works, but it has some flaws. I can add a comma at the beginnings of a string, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the comma's are optional, maybe you need:

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gxa7SV/2)

---

- `^` - Start string ancor
- `\d+` - One or more digits.
- `(?:`- Open non-capture group.

  - `,\d+` - A comma followed but one or more digits.
  - `)*` - Close non-capture group and match zero or more times.
- `$` - End string ancor.

---

***Edit:***

If you actually want to clean a string, maybe you could use:

```
(\d+).*?(,(?=.*\d))|\D
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gxa7SV/4). Just make sure to replace by `$1$2`.

---

- `(\d+)` - 1st Capture group with one or more digits.
- `.*?` - Lazy match anything opto:
- `(,(?=.*\d))` - 2nd Capture group to match literal comma with a nested positive lookahead to ensure there is still a digit ahead.
- `|` - Or:
- `\D` - Anything other than digit.

```js
const regexp = new RegExp(/(\d+).*?(,(?=.*\d))|\D/g);      
const value = '1,2,3'.replace(regexp, '$1$2');
console.log(value)
```

Comment: Probably, my description isn't so clear. They're using method String.prototype.replace. So we need to reverse your answer.

Comment: @MaxBunker, I think I understand your query. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! It almost works, but something is wrong with commas. See the example https://jsbin.com/misizuvaci/edit?js,console,output

Comment: You need to replace with `'$1$2'` instead of `''` @MaxBunker. See the edit to your code.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`^[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*$`

Begins with a digit or a set of digits, followed by zero or more occurrences of a comma followed by one or more digits. Don't miss the start and end line anchors.
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D0wpGd/13)

Comment: This doesn't check for commas at the beginning or the end of the string

Comment: Probably, my description isn't so clear. They're using method String.prototype.replace. So we need to reverse your answer.

Comment: and they are replacing it with what? @MaxBunker

Comment: with an empty string, just delete it. 

pattern="[^0-9,]"

const regexp = new RegExp(pattern);
value = value.replace(regexp, '');

Comment: But now you don't need to replace, just use the matches and ignore the rest

Comment: it may break the project because they use replace everywhere)

Comment: It should not. Changing one usage of a function doesn't break its other occurrences.